# Can parameters be used as default value

Tags: javascript

Can you use a previously defined parameter for defaulting other parameters?

I have an Object with an update function which will update one item in a list.
Therefore I pass a data object into the function and the specified object will be updated.

```
class Device {
    constructor() {
        this.systems = [new System()];
        // ...
    }

    update(data, index) {
        this.systems[index].update(data);
    }
}
```

But I want to call it with the index optional. Meaning assigning the data.index property as a default value.

Not: `new Device().update(data, data.index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `index` in the `data` object, something like that:

```js
function test({ index = 42, ...data } = {}) {
  console.log(index, data);
}

test();
test({ hello: 'world' });
test({ index: 100, a: 'b' });
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work but I'm not sure if it is supposed to be used.

```
function test(a, b = a) {
    return a + b;
}
```

When calling the function with only one parameter `b` will be set to `a`.

`test(2);` will return `4` and `test(2, 3);` will return `5`.

Of course this won't work the other way around.

```
function test2(a = b, a) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Calling `test2(undefined, 2);` will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'b' before initialization` as kind of expected.

The parameter used as a default value must be specified earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

You could to this directly as parameter:

```
function multiply(a, b = a) {
  return a * b;
}
```

Or checking for an undefined

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  b = (typeof b !== 'undefined') ?  b : a;
  return a * b;
}
```

Depends if you want to have it directly as parameter or in the method body.

Have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters